# AttributeError: 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'get' Internal Server Error: /

Tags: python, django

This is the code in modules.py

```
class Payment(models.Model):
cardnumber = CardNumberField(('card number') , default='Card Number')
cardexpiry = CardExpiryField(('expiration date'))
CVV = SecurityCodeField(('security code'), default='cvv')
card_type = models.CharField(max_length=30 , default='Card Type')

def __str__(self):
return self.cardnumber + self.cardexpiry + self.CVV + self.card_type
```

This is the code in forms.py

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from .models import Payment

class paymentForm(ModelForm):
class Meta:
model = Payment
fields = \['cardnumber', 'cardexpiry', 'CVV' ,'card_type'\]
```

This is the code in views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .forms import paymentForm

def payment(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
form = paymentForm(request.POST)
if form.is_valid():
\# Save the form data to the database
form = paymentForm(request)
else:
form = paymentForm()

    return render(request, 'payment.html', {
        'form': form 
        
    })
```

i just want to display the forms in html page + save the update to database

Answer (score 0):

from your post it is not clear if identation is correct and save the form is wrong:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .forms import paymentForm

def payment(request):
   if request.method == 'POST':
      form = paymentForm(request.POST)
      if form.is_valid():
         \# Save the form data to the database
         form.save()
         return render(...)   # render some success page
      else:
         return render(...) # handle invalid data

   else:
      form = paymentForm()

      return render(request, 'payment.html', {
        'form': form 
      })
```